# Title field input not appearing when creating content type by module

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have this problem, I'm creating a content type by creating a module, using the example 'node_example' of examples project as a code template. The thing is that I get it work, I create the content type successfully but when I create a new node of that content type, all fields appear but the title. I'm a little lost. I put by myself the propperty 'has_title' to true on hook_node_info() but it stays the same. Cleared drupal caches several times, removed previous nodes, nothing. Any idea? Thanks.

(Maybe I don't follow all the standards, I'm quite a begginer and I try to follow them as possible) Module name: ct_conversacion. Content type: conversacion.

**-------------edit:**

Ok, it was tough but I found the solution. The function 'ct_conversacion_form' that I wrote below should be 'conversacion_form' (the content type name preceding).

My code:

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_node_info().
   */

      function ct_conversacion_node_info() { 

        return array(
          'conversacion' => array(       
        'name' => t('Conversacion'),   
        'base' => 'conversacion',    
        'description' => t('Es una conversacion.'),  
        'has_title' => TRUE,
        'title_label' => t('Title'),
        'locked' => TRUE,
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implement hook_form().
   */
  function ct_conversacion_form($node, $form_state) {
    return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
  }


  /**
   * Implements hook_node_type_insert(). 
   */

  function ct_conversacion_node_type_insert($content_type) {
    if ($content_type->type == 'conversacion') {  

      $body_instance = node_add_body_field($content_type, t('Mi descripcion')); 

      field_update_instance($body_instance);

      foreach (_conversacion_installed_fields() as $field) {
        field_create_field($field);
      }

      foreach (_conversacion_installed_instances() as $instance) { 
        $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $instance['bundle'] = 'conversacion'; 
        field_create_instance($instance);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Define the fields for our content type.
   *
   */
  function _conversacion_installed_fields() { // Cambiar *****
    return array(
      'conversacion_field2' => array(
        'field_name' => 'conversacion_field2',
        'cardinality' => 3,
        'type'        => 'text',
        'settings'    => array(
          'max_length' => 60,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Define the field instances for our content type.
   */

  function _conversacion_installed_instances() {
    return array(
      'conversacion_field2' => array(
        'field_name' => 'conversacion_field2',
        'label'       => t('Field 2 de Conversacion.'),
        'widget'      => array(
          'type'    => 'text_textfield',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is obviously because you use a wrong base

change it to 'ct_conversacion'

see [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_save/7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_save/7)

base: A string that indicates the base string for hook functions. For example, 'node_content' is the value used by the UI when creating a new node type.